# event after event after event

Tags: jquery

I would make this code one after the other. It's possible?

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
    $('#foo2').animate({opacity: "0"}, function() {
        $(this).load("carousel/todos.html");
        $('#foo2').animate({"opacity":"1"});
        $('#carouselselectitem1').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'opacity' : '1'});
    });
});
```

Comment: not sure understand the question. If you put it in a function, you can call it again and again, or use `setTimeout` to recall it after a time period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question right, you have to use callback functions:

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
    $('#foo2').animate({opacity: "0"}, function() {
        $(this).load("carousel/todos.html", function() {
            $('#foo2').animate({"opacity":"1"}, function() {
                $('#carouselselectitem1').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'opacity' : '1'});                          
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the event with jQuery. Look here: 
[Trigger Event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) there is an example in the bottom, button_2 trigger click event on button_ 1

Answer (score 1):

just test it :

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
    $('#foo2').animate({opacity: "0"},1000 , function() {
        $(this).load("carousel/todos.html");
        $('#foo2').animate({"opacity":"1"},1000,function(){
             $('#carouselselectitem1').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'opacity' : '1'}); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this code works!! but the code of Slevin work more smooth. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback for the `load` function, along with your other callbacks.
I would also recommend caching the selectors.

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function(){
  var carousel = $(this),
      foo2     = $('#foo2');
  foo2.animate({opacity: "0"}, function(){
    foo2.load("carousel/todos.html", function(){
      foo2.animate({opacity:"1"}, function(){
        carousel.css({'background-color' : '#FF0000','opacity' : '1'});
      });
    });
  });
});
```